# Undefined array although it rendered in dom angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, undefined

Here is my Books component that contains books array that I tried to console log. It logs an `undefined` but it shows correctly in DOM after using `*ngFor`.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BooksService } from '../shared/books.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Book } from './book.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-books',
  templateUrl: './books.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./books.component.scss']
})
export class BooksComponent implements OnInit {
  books: Book[];
  filteredBooks: Book[];
  id: string;

  constructor(
    private booksService: BooksService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.booksService.getJson()
      .subscribe(response => (
        this.books = response.json().books)
      );

      console.log(this.books) //undefined;

    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.id = params['id'];
    });
    const filter = this.books.filter(book => book.author === this.id);
    console.log(filter);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting that your service will return value immediately?

Comment: You are making an ajax call, in the subscribe write `console.log(this.books)`, then it will work but outside of subscribe it won't work

Comment: Read about asynchronous code in JavaScript. You are making a service call which is asynchronous and assigning the response to `this.books` sometime once you get the response from server. At the same time browser will parse the  line immediately which results in undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular renders your `books` multiple times. It's `undefined` at first for angular too.

Try putting your `filter` code into your `subscribe`-Block

Answer (score 2):

welcome to Stack Overflow! The problem I see in your code is that you're trying to print the books array before it has been fetched.

The function `getJson()`, you call from `BooksService` is an asynchronous call. Meaning, we don't know how long it might take before this function fetches the books array (might as well fail in some cases).

If you just want to print the list of books, you can do this (Note, I have added an error block to handle errors):

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.booksService.getJson()
    .subscribe(
      response => { // on success
        this.books = response.json().books)
        console.log(this.books); // shows your books!
      },
      error => { // on failure
        console.log('Error Occurred:' + JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    );
  // remaining code ...
}
```

Also in your template (html), you will have to add an `*ngIf` before iterating through these books:

```
<div *ngIf="books">
  <div *ngFor="let book of books">
    <div>{{book.name || 'unknown'}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I strongly recommend you to read a little on **promise chaining**, **Promise.race** or even **callback functions** from one of these sources. You're free to refer elsewhere as well but the first site below (MDN) is a good place to refer anything related to javascript in my opinion :)

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race
- https://javascript.info/promise-chaining
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with this part of the code:

```
this.booksService.getJson()
  .subscribe(response => (
    this.books = response.json().books)
  );

  console.log(this.books) //undefined;
```

HTTP call is asynchronous so the code inside the `.subscribe()` will run after your `console.log(this.books) //undefined;`.

Put `console.log` inside `.subscribe()` method.

```
this.booksService.getJson()
      .subscribe(response => (
        this.books = response.json().books);
        console.log(this.books) //undefined;
      );
```

Actually - you are also reading the `id` from `route.params` - also an asynchronous task. In that case you should combine `booksService.getJSON()` stream with `route.params` stream and do something like that:

```
Observable.combineLatest(
    this.route.params,    //1st stream
    this.booksService.getJson().map(res => res.json().books) //2nd stream   
)
.do((values: any[]) => {
    const id = values[0]['id']; //params from 1st stream
    const allBooks = values[1];        //already mapped books from 2nd stream

    this.filteredBooks = allBooks.filter(book => book.author === id);

}).subscribe();
```